# Python sorted to arrange according to decimal format

Tags: python, sorting

I would like to arrange the list according to the numbering as followed,

```
01
02
03
001
002
```

However default sorted command will give me,

```
001
002
01
02
03
```

Comment: If there is a logic behind your sorting, you can achieve it in Python. But you need to be really clear about it. So first there are numbers with one leading zero, then with two leading zeros, three, ... and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To preserve length ordering over numerical ordering, I believe you need to sort on 2 criteria:

```
nums = '03 01 002 02 001'

num_array = nums.split()
sorted_nums = sorted(num_array, key=lambda x: [len(x), x])

print(sorted_nums)
```

Output:

```
['01', '02', '03', '001', '002']
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, double-sort the list:

```
>>> nums = '03 01 002 02 001'
>>> sorted(sorted(nums.split()),key=len)
['01', '02', '03', '001', '002']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = '001 01 02 03 002'
l = s.split()
print(sorted(l, key=lambda e: (len(e), int(e) )))
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\Desktop>py x.py
['01', '02', '03', '001', '002']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sorted_list = sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: (len(x), x))
```

First it checks the length of the string and then string itself char by char.

Answer (score 0):

```
xs = "01 02 03 001 002".split()
print(sorted(xs, key="{:<018s}".format))
# ['001', '002', '01', '02', '03']
```

Unless you are golfing or decimals have more than 18 decimal places, using two criteria in `key` is probably the way to go.